# Cisco IOS XR: What is an "IID"?

Tags: router

The "show bgp paths" command always returns `1` in the `IID` column. What is an IID? I could not find an explanation by Cisco in any Command Reference or Configuration Guide, not even for IOS.

Here's an example:

```
Proc    IID Refcount     Metric Path
Spk 0   1          4          0 64517 ?
Spk 0   1          2          0 ?
Spk 0   1          3          0 64517 ?
Spk 0   1          3          0 ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is an IID?

It's a Process Instance ID.

> process
>
> To terminate or restart a process, use the process command in the
>   System Admin EXEC mode.
>
> `process { crash | restart } executable-name { IID location node-id |
>   location node-id }`
>
> ...
>
> `IID` Process instance ID of the process to be crashed or restarted.
>   Supplying a process ID for the IID argument performs the action for
>   only the process instance associated with the process ID.

Source [Chapter: Process Control Commands](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/ncs6000/software/system_admin/command/reference/b_sysadmin_cr50xncs6008/b_sysadmin_cr50xncs6008_chapter_0110.html)